# Object ID error when reading PDF file with PyPDF2

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I trying to merge two PDF files. But already when laoding the first, an error occures.

I use the following code:

```
    from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
    pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter()

    for file in files:
        pdf_reader = PdfFileReader(file)
       for page in range(pdf_reader.getNumPages()):

   ....
```

nothing special. But in line 5 I already get the following error:

```
>---------------------------------------------------------------------------
>PdfReadError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-dfb68038ddd0> in <module>
      4 for file in files:
      5     pdf_reader = PdfFileReader(file)
----> 6     for page in range(pdf_reader.getNumPages()):
      7         pdf_writer.addPage(pdf_reader.getPage(page))
      8 

>C:\Miniconda3\envs\wc_test\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py in getNumPages(self)
   1153         else:
   1154             if self.flattenedPages == None:
-> 1155                 self._flatten()
   1156             return len(self.flattenedPages)
   1157 

>C:\Miniconda3\envs\wc_test\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py in _flatten(self, pages, inherit, indirectRef)
   1503         if pages == None:
   1504             self.flattenedPages = []
-> 1505             catalog = self.trailer["/Root"].getObject()
   1506             pages = catalog["/Pages"].getObject()
   1507 

>C:\Miniconda3\envs\wc_test\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\generic.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    514 
    515     def __getitem__(self, key):
--> 516         return dict.__getitem__(self, key).getObject()
    517 
    518     ##

>C:\Miniconda3\envs\wc_test\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\generic.py in getObject(self)
    176 
    177     def getObject(self):
--> 178         return self.pdf.getObject(self).getObject()
    179 
    180     def __repr__(self):

>C:\Miniconda3\envs\wc_test\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py in getObject(self, indirectReference)
   1607                 # some other problem
   1608                 raise utils.PdfReadError("Expected object ID (%d %d) does not match actual (%d %d)." \
-> 1609                                          % (indirectReference.idnum, indirectReference.generation, idnum, generation))
   1610             assert generation == indirectReference.generation
   1611             retval = readObject(self.stream, self)

>PdfReadError: Expected object ID (1 0) does not match actual (3 1).
```

I do not know what is wrong with this pdf file, it works on other PDF which are not different. 
Searching for answers did not make me understand what is wrong here, I actually still have no clue. Merging the PDFs using Adobe Reader Pro works however...no errors, but I need to merge many files automatically. Any help is welcome.

**Solved**

I opened the PDFs in question using a text-editor and compared to working ones. The two first line were new lines (\n) causing this error. I just removed them and saved the pdf -> working. However, this issue is due to an update of a plugin i use in Wordpress.

Comment: It may be either a document or PyPDF2 issue. Try to use another readers like https://pypi.org/project/pdfreader/ or https://pypi.org/project/pdfminer/

Answer (score 0):

PyPDF2 has received many updates in 2022. This sounds like a bug that likely was fixed.

You should use `pypdf` as PyPDF2 was merged back into pypdf. PyPDF2 is no longer supported.